# pgadmin4 6.21: keywords like "SERIAL" or "VARCHAR" are not being highlighted

Tags: pgadmin-4

I recently downloaded the `6.21` version of `pgadmin4`, but encountered an error that is bothering me. Every time I write keywords like **SERIAL** or **VARCHAR** (which used to be highlighted in *yellow* until the 6.12 version) they continue to appear in the same color as `non-keywords`, such as `column_name`

[image]

Does anybody know anything about it?

(also, if there's anyway to highlight NULL in red, I would appreciate it)

Comment: `File > Preferences > Query Tool > Syntax highlighting > Enable syntax highlighting` Is it checked ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I’d report an issue to them

Comment: @Tushar I didn't find `Syntax highlighting` within `Query Tool` in pgadmin4 6.21. 
@DanielA.White I'll report it. 

Could you guys upvote this question, so I can get more help?